# Place image on the ActionBar on the center of the screen

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-actionbar

I want to place company logo on the center of ActionBar (absolutely center of the screen). How can I calculate central point (by width) of the screen precisely?

Activity code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_layout, null);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

action_bar_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

- I've  placed this icon for example.
  [image]

Have any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Simple Answer is that you should use a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` and set `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` on the `ImageView`. Skip the two placeholder views.

I would Advise you to use a `ToolBar` instead though (Which requires you to use the support library). Place the RelativeLayout inside the ToolBar with width=height=match_parent. Then in your activity, do the following

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Comment: I realize now that maybe you meant how to place the Icon in the middle of the back button and left-most action icon?

Comment: It seems the same with LinearLayout. The problem is to place image on the center of the screen, not in the center of layout.

Comment: If what you want is to have the image on the exact center of the screen, it will work if you try the ToolBar solution I proposed.

Comment: I dont know what is toolbar and R.id.toolbar. Can you explain it for me?